# Error while installing gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185716/problem-with-gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme)

While trying to install this package, I get this error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme : Depends:
gnome-shell-extensions-common but it is not going to be installed 

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How I can fix it ?

Comment: Have you tried sudo apt-get update? Before you try what you are attempting to do?

Comment: @NlightNfotis of course I've tried `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme`