# Problem with gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme

Tags: gnome, package-management

I'm trying to install themes with gnome tweak, and I need to install `gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme` because otherwise I cannot see the shell extensions tab. However, I cannot install shell extensions. I have tried to install by adding the PPA with the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
```

Then,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally, when I try to install:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
```

It gives an error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme : Depends: gnome-shell-extensions-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am convinced that there is a problem with the package. So I went on and tried to install the extensions from the website:
https://extensions.gnome.org/

But even though I use Firefox (15.0), I cannot see the "switch" that is being mentioned to install the extension. Maybe the version of Firefox is too new.

Is there any workaround that you know of?

(By the way, I use Ubuntu 12.04, freshly downloaded and installed.)

Comment: try "sudo apt-get install -f"

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late, but if you go to the Ubuntu Software Center and search for the Gnome Shell Common package (gnome-shell-common) it will install all of the common files required here.

Please note: as the source file for the user-themes extension is provided and modified by a party outside of the included source repositories for the gnome-shell installation, compatibility cannot be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

first remove it completely by -

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
```

Try following commands -

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Its seems the issue is your broken Downloads , so use -

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then try installing `gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme` again

```
sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
```

hope it will work.If it still have problems than try to install it manually as follows-

[Download gnome-shell-extensions from here](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell-extensions) and then install it.

or use this one line command for installing gtk 3.8.3.10 -

```
cd ~ && mkdir -p .blumixinstall && cd .blumixinstall && wget https://github.com/rhoconlinux/Blumix/archive/master.zip && unzip master.zip && cd Blumix-master/ && sudo cp -a Blumix/ /usr/share/themes/ && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Blumix" && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "Blumix" && rm -Rf ~/.blumixinstall && cd ~
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding the PPA and then updating the repositories,run the below command,

```
sudo aptitude install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
```